# Почему не обособляется "по своему возрасту"?

Tags: пунктуация, дополнение

> Ребёнку шёл четвёртый год, и он **по своему возрасту** был хорошо развит.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Полное предложение:

*Ему шёл четвёртый год, и он по своему возрасту был хорошо развит, говорил почти чисто и забавно, сообразиловка его крепко работала хоть в играх, хоть в запоминании песен, стишков или там всяких посказулек.* [Виктор Астафьев. Пролетный гусь (2000)]

Обособление обстоятельства "***по своему возрасту***" факультативно. Автор решил не акцентировать на нем внимание.

[**Обстоятельства, выраженные существительными**](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=114) (Справочник Розенталя)

> Для смыслового выделения или для пояснения могут обособляться (выделяться запятыми) обстоятельства, выраженные существительными в формах косвенных падежей (обычно с предлогами)...
>
> Во многих случаях <...> обособление или необособление обстоятельства зависит от степени распространенности оборота, его близости к основной части предложения, наличия добавочных оттенков значения, места по отношению к сказуемому, стилистической задачи и т. д., поэтому обособление **факультативно**.

Answer (score 3):

Факультативное обособление обстоятельств, выраженных падежными формами,  определяется семантикой оборота и структурой предложения.

1) *Ребёнку шёл четвёртый год, и он **по своему возрасту** был хорошо рАзвит, говорил почти чисто и забАвно...*

При обособлении оборот приобретает **уточняющее значение**, но при этом очень важна **структура** предложения (не каждый оборот можно обособить). В заданном предложении основная интонация строится на выделении **однородного ряда сказуемых,** поэтому выделять оборот внутри одного из сказуемых неудобно.

2) Вариант с обособлением приведен для сравнения.

*Кроме того, горя энтузиазмом и не имея возможности, **по своему возрасту**, сражаться, он занялся журналистикой и помещает статьи в «Заре Авиньона», а также устраивает различные патриотические собрания.* [И. Г. Эренбург. Необычайные похождения Хулио Хуренито (1921)]

Здесь по смыслу оборот имеет значение попутного уточнения, поэтому автор расположил его в позиции, **удобной для обособления** (оборот разделяет словосочетание "не имея возможности () сражаться").  При чтении оборота используется "вставочная интонация".